# Send private message to a specific user with message dialog using the android sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I want to be able to open the private message dialog using the facebook android sdk ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#message-dialog)

But I want to be able to set the target user for the message so the user won't have to do it by himself. There is an option to do it in the javascript api like this:

```
    FB.ui({
    app_id : app_id,
    method : 'send',
    to : uid, 
    link : link,
    display : 'popup',
    redirect_uri : 'url')}
```

But I couldn't find a way to do it with the MessageDialogBuilder in the android sdk.

Thanks, tom.

Comment: i don´t think it´s possible, but why not just let the user select?

Comment: It's a required feature for my app. The user is sending a message with a question about a product that the target user sells, they are not friends in facebook.